# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x^{n})}{n!}$ converges uniformly for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x^{n})}{n!}$ converges uniformly for $x \in \mathbb R$ to a $C^{1}$ function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, compute an expression for the derivative.

My attempt: For uniform convergence, It is clear that $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x^{n})}{n!}|<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$.

By comparison test, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ is convergent. So by WM test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x^{n})}{n!}$ converges uniformly for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Can anyone suggest me about the second part?
Is the question about term by term differentiation?

Comment: Can you do term-by-term differentiation?

Comment: @User124356 Recall that $ e = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} \ldots $ so then your infinite sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} = e-1$ . I don't know if this will help I just saw that and thought I would add this.

Comment: Your proof of uniform convergence looks weird. Instead of bounding the sum, you should bound each term. If WM stands for Weirsrass M test, then you indeed need to bound each term.

Comment: @Michael do you mean by this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x^{n})}{n!}=\frac{sin(x)}{1!}+\frac{sin(x^{2})}{2!}+\frac{sin(x^{3})}{3!}+.........+\frac{sin(x^{n})}{n!}$. Then I take mod to bound the terms?

Comment: Can you set $y=sin(x^n)$ so that it converges to $e^y-1$ and use the chain rule?

Comment: I just mean $\left|\frac{sin(x^n)}{n!}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n!}$. So your proof sentences are almost the same, but they should acknowledge that the Wierstrass M test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(t)$ requires $|f_n(t)|\leq M_n$ not $|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(t)|\leq M_n$.  Here is a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: @CyclotomicField : Unless I misunderstand you, I don't think the $y = sin(x^n)$ transformation makes sense, since the left-hand-side does not depend on $n$, and the right-hand-side does, and this is important because $n$ is an index that changes in the summation.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(x^n)}{n!}$ converges uniformly for $x\in\mathbb R$, we may differentiate term-by-term:

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(x^n)}{n!} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}\cos(x^n)}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}\cos(x^n)}{(n-1)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\cos(x^{n-1})}{n!}\\
\end{align}
I do not know how to further simplify this, and will defer that to someone with more expertise.

Comment: I think the assertion is incomplete, for example: 
Define $f_n(x) =\frac{\sin\left(x^{(n^4)}\right)}{n^2}$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, …\}$.  Then 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges uniformly for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but
we cannot differentiate term-by-term.

Comment: It converges absolutely as well. What else is needed for term-by-term differentiation?